# How do you do a web search on an IPhone?

Tags: iphone, safari

My current workflow to do a web search is to:

1. Open the Safari app
2. Click on the "tabs" button
3. Open a new tab
4. Type my search query into the URL bar.

But I'm constantly frustrated by typos due to the lack of autocompletion (which I guess is turned off automatically in this field). Is there a more canonical way to do a web search? Do I have to ask Siri? Not my preference since I don't want to have to talk aloud. And I don't want to use the Chrome or Google apps since I can't live without the ad-blocker in Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just swipe down on any home screen to reveal the search field at top of screen. Enter your search criteria and you'll see a range of results, including suggested websites.

If none of the results suit you, just swipe up and tap on the Search Web option that appears at the bottom of screen. This will do a search for you using Google (or whatever search engine you have set as your default) in a new Safari tab.

**NOTES:**

- It may be worth you checking whether you've configured Spotlight Suggestions. You can do this via Settings > General > Spotlight Search.
- You can also check your Safari Search settings within Settings > Safari.